# Array gets empty when tried to run on a script

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript that upon process of an ajax call will get a certain value then store it in an array. I don't know why but I set my Array as a global variable but when I try to call it on another function the length returns 0;

Why is it when I try to get the length of an array using a different function it returns zero? but when I include it after the for loop on the first function it can generate the length correctly? Isn't it when you declare a variable as GLOBAL it means that you can use it anywhere and in any functions? Please help me and make me realize my mistakes.

Sorry for being a newb here is the actual code:

```
var distMatLink = [];

function searchNearMarkers(distance){
    clearLocations();
    document.getElementById('errorNotifs').innerHTML = "";
    //document.getElementById('checkboxes').innerHTML = '';     
    var searchUrl = '...some url here...'
    downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data){
        var xml = parseXml(data);
        var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++){
            var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
            var info = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("info");
            var budget = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("budget");
            var tts = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("tts");
            var type = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("type");
            var distance = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance");
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            storeArray (i,markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat"),markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng"));
            bounds.extend(latlng);
            if (i == (markerNodes.length - 1)){
                bounds.extend(userPosLatLng);
            }
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

    });

    countArray();
}

function storeArray(i,lat,lng){
      distMatLink[i] = "|"+lat+ "," +lng+""; 
}

function countArray(){
      alert(distMatLink.length);
}
```

Comment: It's because you're using AJAX, and the order of execution isn't what you think because of what that first A (asynchronous) means. Anything that relies on the response of an AJAX request should be called from the function that handles the response.

Comment: Are you using javascript AJAX or jquery AJAX?

Comment: You've posted example code that doesn't reproduce your problem, so we cannot help you. Your code alerts `10`, exactly as it should. Your question needs to include an minimal complete example that **reproduces your problem**, not a snippet of code that works fine.

Comment: I already included the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a commenter mentioned, Ajax is performing this asynchronously. To fix this function you'll have to do something like this:

```
function createMe(result){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       someArray[i] = i;
       if(i == 9){
          result(someArray)
       }
    }
}

function countMe(){
   createMe(function(results){
      alert(results)
   })
}
```

The reason for this is Ajax is running the countMe() function before the loop is finished, thus your array looks empty. The above functions use callbacks to ensure the function is done before moving on to finish countMe(). Now instead of using createMe to initialize, use countMe and when CreatMe finishes, countMe will alert the results.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you will most probably be having is that you are executing the `.length` function even before the `AJAX` request has been completed. You must set the global variable in the callback of the `AJAX` request.

Something similar to these lines if using `jQuery`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(responseData, status){
        if(status == 'success') {
            myglobalarray = parse(responseData);
        }
    }
});
```

Something similar to these lines if using plain `Javascript`:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     myglobalarray = parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}
```

Comment: but to what I understand on my code is I let the loop finished first before calling the function that will count the array length. When I inserted an alert(array.length) before the code, the array gets counted but when the countArray was called it returned 0

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what is happening. Your `downloadUrl` is being executed asynchronously. So, as soon as you register this call, the `countArray` method gets executed immediately after irrespective of `downloadUrl` being executed fully or not. I would suggest you shift it to the callback function of the `downloadUrl` method.